# What is the fundamental solution of this homogeneous system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation, fundamental-solution

What is the fundamental solution of this homogeneous system of linear equations? And what are the steps to solving one?
$$\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        x_1+3x_2-5x_3+9x_4-x_5=0 \\
        2x_1-2x_2-3x_3-7x_4+2x_5=0 \\
        x_1-5x_2+2x_3-16x_4+3x_5=0
    \end{array}
\right.$$

I had this exact task in a test and couldn't wrap my mind around it. I'd appreciate a more or less simple answer as I'm not a native English speaker.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would the answer to ''finding a fundamental solution'' be - there is none, because there is an infinite amount of solutions? Or should I have x3=c3; x4=c4; x5=c5 and then make a solution out of that? Meaning x2=7/8*c3 - 25/8*c4+1/2*c5 etc.? I'm wondering if that counts as a fundamental solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the right side of each equation is 0, it is trivial that $x_1= x_2= x_3= x_4= x_5= 0$ is a solution.  But since there are three equations in five unknowns, there exist other, non trivial solutions.

One way to find all possible solutions is to start **trying** to solve the equations.  For example, if we multiply the first equation by 2 and subtract from the second equation we eliminate both $x_1$ and $x_5$: $-8x_2+ 7x_3- 25x_4= 0$. If we multiply the *third* equation by 2 and subtract from the second equation, we eliminate $x_1$ again: $14x_2- 7x_3+ 25x_4- 4x_5= 0$.  And if we add those two equations, we eliminate both $x_3$ and $x_4$: 6x_2- 4x_5= 0.  From that $x_5= \frac{3}{2}x_2$.  Putting that into $14x_2- 7x_3+ 25x_4- 4x_5= 0$ we get $8x_2- 7x_3+ 25x_1= 0$.  Solving that for $x_1$, $x_1= \frac{7}{25}x_3- \frac{8}{25}x_2$.  We are through with the equations so this is as far as we can go.  writing "A" for $x_3$ and "B" for $x_2$, $x_1= \frac{7}{25}A- \frac{8}{25}B$, $x_2= A$, $x_4= B$, and you can solve for $x_3$ and $x_5$ in terms of A and B.